# jQuery UI sortable - can't add item to bottom of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to create a app that has some sortable lists.  There is a list of categories which are sortable, and each category has a list of items which is also sortable.  Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".items" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".items",
    placeholder: 'item placeholder',
  });
  $( ".categories" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".categories",
    placeholder: {
      element: function(currentItem) {
        return $('<div class="category placeholder"></div>')[0];
      },
      update: function(container, p) {
        container.refreshPositions();
        return;
      }
    }
  });

  $( ".items" ).disableSelection();
  $( ".categories" ).disableSelection();

});
```

See this jsfiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/conman124/GmDBw/

The problem that I am encountering is that it is not easy to move an item from one category to the bottom of the other.  It seems like you have to drag it to be the second to last item in the list, and then you can move it down to the bottom.  I have looked at this ([jQuery UI sortable - unable to drag elements to the bottom of a connected list/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511391/jquery-ui-sortable-unable-to-drag-elements-to-the-bottom-of-a-connected-list-c)) similiar question and adding the padding at the bottom like in that question didn't seem to fix it.

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It must just be problems with my setup.

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm having the exact same problem, and I've yet to find a solution.  Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Apparently, this is a regression bug that has been fixed, but the fix has not been released as of this time (jquery-ui 1.10.3 and 1.10.4)- http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9314